# Loop error in java

Tags: java, for-loop

I am trying to make a method that searches a String array for an inputted state and returns the index. If the user enters a query that is not in the array, I would like it to ask for a new state to search. At the moment I am stuck in the loop. I know I am entering a valid state, but it keeps asking for a valid state and will out let me out of the loop.

Thank you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    String[] stateNames = importFile("stateNames.txt");
    String[] nicknames = importFile("nicknames.txt");
    String[] populations = importFile("population.txt");
    String[] flowers = importFile("flowers.txt");
    String[] Capital = importFile("capitals.txt");
    int index = askState(stateNames);
     System.out.println("The index of your state is"+ index);
}
static final int NUM_STATES = 50;

public static String[] importFile(String fileName) throws
        FileNotFoundException {

    String[] array = new String[NUM_STATES];

    File inputFile = new File(fileName);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputFile);


    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_STATES; i++) {
        array[i] = scanner.nextLine();

    }
    return array;

}

public static int askState(String[] stateNames) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String state;
    int statePosition = -1;
    System.out.println("Please enter a state that you would like to search:");
    state = keyboard.nextLine();
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_STATES; i++) {
            if (state.equals(stateNames[i])) 
                statePosition = i;
                else {
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid state:");
            state = keyboard.next();
            }}
        return statePosition;

    }

    }
```

}

Comment: You tell the user to enter a valid state as soon as you find an item in the array that is not equal to the entered state. You must do that only when you're sure that ALL the items in the array are different from the entered state. And you'll only know that once you've examined every element of the array. My advice: write a method `int indexOfItemInArray(String[] array, String item)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
    public static int askState(String[] stateNames) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String state;
    int statePosition = -1;
    System.out.println("Please enter a state that you would like to search:");
    state = keyboard.nextLine();
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_STATES; i++) {
            if (state.equals(stateNames[i])){ 
                statePosition = i;
                return stateposition;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid state:");          
    }
    return statePosition;

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You you get used to the collection classes in Java. If you are not required to use a loop, I would import the items to a Set, you can then ask the set if an element is present.
See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html

Though it does not matter in your case, the performance of a Set is better on the long run, compared to searching arrays the brute-force way.

Regarding your specific question: Make sure that you really have the same values in the array as entered by the user. You can test it, using a simple 'equals()' with a dummy array containing just one state and entering that yourself.